# Configuring hibernate.cfg.xml file

Tags: java, hibernate

I am new to Hibernate, so I have few dumb questions hope someone would be able to assist me. I have a query in regards to configuring hibernate file i.e. hibernate.cfg.xml file. Normally we configure it as below :

```
  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>  
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC  
              "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"  
              "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">  
<hibernate-configuration>  

<session-factory>  
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>  
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect</property>  
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe</property>  
    <property name="connection.username">system</property>  
    <property name="connection.password">oracle</property>  
    <property name="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>  
<mapping resource="employee.hbm.xml"/>  
</session-factory>  

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Where the  considers relevant mapping files. Lets say I have another mapping file, call it company.hbm.xml file and have a one-to-many relationship with  employee.hbm.xml file. So, as and when the number of mapping files increases we include them into  tag.

Query : How is it different to include multiple mapping files with individual  tag from having just a single mapping file with all the relevant mappings.

Appreciate your response

Comment: Why don't you use **annotation** in your model classes instead creating multiple mapping files?

Comment: This is the drawback of using xml , bcz xml file shall be increased for multiple relationships to many entities . so you could try it out with annotation in pojo's and config entity  in hibernate.cfg.xml file

Comment: Is there any scenario where we will give priority to use mapping files instead of annotation ?

Answer (score 0):

Because such separation is cleaner. Single file with whole configuration tends to grow up and to become a yet another huge, unmaintainable and unreadable XML file.

Please also note, that using annotations right inside your model classes seems to be the right way for you (just as @Shiju Babu stated).

Comment: And for the xml/annotation topic. Annotations were introduced in the 5th release of Java - so if you use Java 1.5 or above, you should use them firstly. XML is considered a kind of 'deprecated' way of configuration in this case. Keeping metadata close to the related classes and data is a good practise - easier to understand and maintain your code.

Comment: Is there any scenario where we will give priority to use mapping files instead of annotation ?